# Change [iphone-app] to [iphone], like [android]

Tags: discussion, tags

The `android` tag and `iphone-app` tags should be brought into alignment.  I recommend changing `iphone-app` to just `iphone`.  Do others agree?

Comment: Related, where the change was made: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1063/46

Comment: Quoting the relevant part: *I still think the `*-app` tags should remain, if for consistency: we also have `web-app` and not `web` :) If you'll remind me of `android` not having the `-app` suffix: **that's an OS, not a device.***

Comment: When someone wants an iPhone app, is it best for them to tag it with both "ios" and "iphone-app" or is the "ios" implied?  If it's implied, it adds complexity to searches for iOS apps.

Comment: @Undo Thanks for the link to the other meta thread!  Worthwhile reading.

Comment: That merge seems to have evaporated: both are separate tags again. I've tried to merge them as suggested here (it's an OS tag, so it should be "iphone" – also [see here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/434/185)) – but ran into an "oops". A detailed error report automatically was forwareded to the devs, so I think we should hear back from them.